# Management software similar to Dell OpenManage for Cisco UCS rack servers?

Tags: cisco-ucs

Deploying some new Cisco UCS C220 M3 rack servers and was wondering if there is any management software similar to Dell's OpenManage that I should install on each server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage and monitor all blade servers in a Cisco UCS domain through Cisco UCS Manager. Some blade server management tasks, such as changes to the power state, can be performed from the server and service profile.The remaining management tasks can only be performed on the server.

Comment: Do I have to install anything on the server to support Cisco UCS Manager, or just normal OS install and I'm good to go?

Comment: For common stuff, just the normal OS installation. From the UCS manager you can add or delete equipment from "Equipment > Chassis > Chassis Number > Servers ". Again I recently started playing with this management utility.